# Как продолжить конструкцию if else в override методе c# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

В программировании новичок и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть у меня virual метод

```
protected virtual void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Могу ли я override метод

```
protected override void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    base.OnCollisionEnter2D(collision);
}
```

продолжить с else? Если нет то как тогда лучше оформить данный участок кода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Условие придется проверить повторно.

```
protected override void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    base.OnCollisionEnter2D(collision);

    if (!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        // тут то, что вы хотели в else написать
    }
}
```

Или так

```
protected override void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    base.OnCollisionEnter2D(collision);

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        return;

    // тут то, что вы хотели в else написать
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите вызвать логику `SceneManager.LoadScene` если `gameObject` является `Player`, иначе вызвать базовый метод.
В таком случае, можно попробовать вот такую конструкцию.

```
protected virtual void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        return;
    }

    base.OnCollisionEnter2D(collision);
}
```

Правильно ли я вас понял? Если нет - опишите проблему подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня есть два класса:  родительский класс Enemy и дочерний MovingEnemy. В родительском классе мне хватает того, что при соприкосновении с gameObject.Player сцена перезагружается, а вот в MovingEnemy в методе OnCollisionEnter2D я бы хотел дописать условие для столкновения с другими объектами. Можно было бы просто в дочернем классе переписать весь метод и добавить else, но мне интересно как это можно сделать не переписывая код, а основываясь на виртуальном методе родительского класса Enemy.